# Using objects as options in Autoform

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2, simple-schema

In my `Stacks` schema i have a `dimensions` property defined as such:

```
dimensions: {
    type: [String],
    autoform: {
        options: function() {
            return Dimensions.find().map(function(d) {
                return { label: d.name, value: d._id };
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This works really well, and using Mongol I'm able to see that an attempt to insert data through the form worked well (in this case I chose two dimensions to insert)

[image: Mongol image]

However what I really what is data that stores the actual dimension object rather than it's key. Something like this:

[[image: Mongol good[2]]

To try to achieve this I changed `type:[String]` to `type:[DimensionSchema]` and `value: d._id` to `value: d`. The thinking here that I'm telling the form that I am expecting an object and am now returning the object itself.

However when I run this I get the following error in my console.

> Meteor does not currently support objects other than ObjectID as ids

Poking around a little bit and changing `type:[DimensionSchema]` to `type: DimensionSchema` I see some new errors in the console (presumably they get buried when the `type` is an array

[image: console image]

So it appears that autoform is trying to take the value I want stored in the database and trying to use that as an id. Any thoughts on the best way to do this?.

For reference here is my `DimensionSchema`

```
export const DimensionSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        label: "Name"
    },
    value: {
        type: Number,
        decimal: true,
        label: "Value",
        min: 0

    },
    tol: {
        type: Number,
        decimal: true,
        label: "Tolerance"
    },
    author: {
        type: String,
        label: "Author",
        autoValue: function() {
            return this.userId
        },
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        }
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        label: "Created At",
        autoValue: function() {
            return new Date()
        },
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/issues/798) issue?

Comment: @MasterAM nope. That pretty much covers it. Thanks for giving me closure.

Comment: Question is, are you sure that you want to embed the entire document? Maybe you only need a subset? Is there any chance that a `dimension` would change in the future (and if so, how do you plan to update the nested documents in a maintainable way)? You could also use a Meteor method to handle the form and do everything there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my experience and aldeed himself in [this issue](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/issues/798), autoform is not very friendly to fields that are arrays of objects.

I would generally advise against embedding this data in such a way. It makes the data more difficult to maintain in case a `dimension` document is modified in the future.

## alternatives

- You can use a package like [publish-composite](https://github.com/englue/meteor-publish-composite) to create a reactive-join in a publication, while only embedding the `_id`s in the `stack` documents.
- You can use something like the [PeerDB](https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-peerdb) package to do the de-normalization for you, which will also update nested documents for you. Take into account that it comes with a learning curve.
- Manually code the specific forms that cannot be easily created with AutoForm. This gives you maximum control and sometimes it is easier than all of the tinkering.

## if you insist on using AutoForm

While it may be possible to [create a custom input type](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#defining-custom-input-types) (via `AutoForm.addInputType()`), I would not recommend it. It would require you to create a template and modify the data in its `valueOut` method and it would not be very easy to generate edit forms.

Since this is a specific use case, I believe that the best approach is to use a slightly **modified schema** and handle the data in a **Meteor method**.

Define a schema with an array of strings:

```
export const StacksSchemaSubset = new SimpleSchema({
  desc: {
    type: String
  },
  ...
  dimensions: {
    type: [String],
    autoform: {
      options: function() {
        return Dimensions.find().map(function(d) {
            return { label: d.name, value: d._id };
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Then, render a quickForm, specifying a schema and a method:

```
<template name="StacksForm">
  
  {{> quickForm
    schema=reducedSchema
        id="createStack"
        type="method"
        meteormethod="createStack"
        omitFields="createdAt"
  }}

</template>
```

And define the appropriate helper to deliver the schema:

```
Template.StacksForm.helpers({
  reducedSchema() {
    return StacksSchemaSubset;
  }
});
```

And on the server, define the method and mutate the `data` before inserting.

```
Meteor.methods({
  createStack(data) {
    // validate data
    const dims = Dimensions.find({_id: {$in: data.dimensions}}).fetch(); // specify fields if needed
    data.dimensions = dims;
    Stacks.insert(data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i can advise at this moment (if the values doesnt support `object` type), is to convert object into `string`(i.e. serialized string) and set that as the value for "dimensions" key (instead of object) and save that into DB.

And while getting back from db, just unserialize that value (`string`) into `object` again.